# How to make OCaml bytecode that works on Windows and Linux

Tags: ocaml

I want to compile some OCaml bytecode and have it run on Windows and Unix-type systems. My source code works fine if I recompile it on each platform, but the bytecode isn't portable.

Sample code:

```
open Unix

let on_windows = Filename.dir_sep <> "/";;
Printf.printf "On windows: %b\n" on_windows;;

let child = create_process "gpg" (Array.of_list ["gpg"; "--version"]) stdin stdout stderr;;
Printf.printf "Child %d\n" child;;
```

Build command:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg unix test.byte
```

If I compile on Windows and run on Linux, I get

```
Fatal error: unknown C primitive `win_waitpid'
```

If I compile on Linux and run on Windows I get:

```
Fatal error: unknown C primitive `unix_waitpid'
```

How can I make the bytecode work everywhere?

Comment: Please show the compilation command.

Comment: I'm using ocamlbuild - I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely renaming the C symbols doesn't work because there are two completely different versions of the unix.ml module (though with the same interface). If you link your code statically, you'll get the one for the build platform and it won't work on the other platform.

The solution is to create and distribute a .cma archive (with the Unix module not linked in) rather than an executable. Then use `ocaml` to link dynamically on the target platform:

http://roscidus.com/blog/blog/2013/07/07/ocaml-binary-compatibility/#windows--linux-compatibility

**Update:** This isn't safe. When you do `ocaml /path/to/script.ml`, it adds the current directory (not the directory containing the script) to the start of the search path. Thus:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ /usr/bin/myprog
```

will first try to load myprog's libraries (e.g. `unix.cma`) from `/tmp`.

Should be fixed in 4.03: http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6081

Answer (score 8):

Obviously, the reason is that ocaml unix library has different names for C stubs depending on the platform, and this hinders bytecode portability. I do not see the way out except for patching stub names..

Comment: How do I do that (patch stub names)?

Comment: You have to install (at least) mingw under windows. You can try to hack you package by adding mingw DLL in the PATH and to launch bytecode then

Comment: Looks like win_waitpid is an OCaml function, not a mingw one (not that I know anything about this). http://caml.inria.fr/svn/ocaml/branches/sse2/otherlibs/win32unix/winwait.c

Comment: I would attempt to go to win32unix sources and replace win_ with unix_ in function names in .c files and "external" declarations in unix.ml. Seemingly some of the functions in win32unix have unix_ prefix and some win_ - don't know why. I guess eliminating this difference will benefit bytecode portability of unix library.

Comment: Apparently the windows implementation lacks a lot of primitives (look at the win32unix/unix.ml module code). Maybe they wanted to allow the inclusion of both modules on platforms permitting it (ie. windows with unix services installed). I agree with the suggested solution to renames the C primitives in the windows code.